# Calulate Derivate of function of function with multiple variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to calculate following:
$ \partial h(r(g(f(x^2 - 2xy + y^2))))/\partial y$

Can you please tell me if my solution given below is correct ?:

$= \partial h(r(g(−2x+2y)))/\partial y$

$= \partial h(r(g(2)))/\partial y$

$= \partial h(r(0))/\partial y $

$= \partial h(0)/\partial y $

=$ 0 $

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} h(r(g(f(x^2-2xy+y^2))))=\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(r(g(f(x^2-2xy+y^2))))\times \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}(g(f(x^2-2xy+y^2)))\times \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(f(x^2-2xy+y^2))\times \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^2-2xy+y^2)\times (-2x+2y)$$
by chain rule. I'm not really sure where you getting your answer.

**Edit:** I see where you went wrong. You nested your chain rule backwards.